# How to get server url from kub dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have access to kubernetes dashboard on aws with token. And now I want to connect with kubectl, how to get server url for kubectl config?

Answer (score 1):

When running an EKS cluster, the best way to configure your `~/.kube/config` is by using the [SDK's update-kubeconfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/eks/update-kubeconfig.html):

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name your-cluster-name
```

Make sure to configure your credentials as `AWS_*` environment variables. Or even better use something like [aws-vault](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault).

Comment: for this I need to have access to aws cli, but I only have access to kub dashboard, so I wonder if it possible to get kubernetes server api from there

Comment: You should be able to see the Cluster URL via the web console. Just navigate to your cluster via the EKS menu and look for the API Server URL.